# system ( com.Android google.com.gms ) share from gallery app suddenly stops working and crashes

Tags: share-menu, android-10, java, crash-reports

there is a prominent `gallery` app that I am using  -`f-stop` .
been using it for very long time and never had this issue .
`gallery` app itself seems to be working but when I select more than one picture and invoke `system share` so I can   share  those with other apps like `WhatsApp`... everything crashes.
it gives me an option to view the  app log  crash in an email attachment, that it prepared to send to Google for feedback unfortunately selfish as it may sound, I cannot send that attachment to my email   It just directly sends it without even keeping a sent copy in my Gmail. using some kind of a hack I pulled up all that log info and I am putting it in  [`pastebin_with_crash_log_info`](https://pastebin.com/KxMA1zUh)

The relevant error is:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08007a
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:246)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:905)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:880)
at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$TargetPresentationGetter.loadIconFromResource(ResolverActivity.java:669)
```

here are the more relevant details

crashing system share app concerned is

```
com.Android google.com.gms

Source file
ResourcesImpl.java
Source class
android.content.res.ResourcesImpl
Source method
getValueForDensity
Line number
246
```

os details

```
magisk rooted Android q project treble ROM
```

Comment: I would assume that one of the installed apps that are listed in the shared apps list has a problem loading the app icon. Unfortunately the error log has no indicator which app icon fails to load. What apps have you recently installed or updated?

Comment: Is there any log related to `ResolverActivity$TargetPresentationGetter.getLabel()`? Based on the code, it should state the application name.

Comment: @Robert gotcha you nailed it ! yes indeed there was that one app that I actually installed offline from a SD card second partition and apparently the app had changed maybe that app could be a split kind of app. once I removed that we are good to go. if you post that comment as an answer I will accept it   thank you  `stay home stay safe`. let's all drive thru this dark fog  , into good sunlight and hopefully soon.!

Comment: is there any way I can control the the the system share app list I would like to trim that list and remove apps that are of no use and collapse `WhatsApp` menu at the same time also want to manually add in that list certain apps that don't auto. show up in system share. I'd imagine the latter would be e difficult to accomplish just bi admin means. but is there something I can change in terms of app property file like `manifest` file to ensure that the app shows up in `system share` menu . would changing  config files as a root still cause  changes in apps signature &  other complications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the error seems to be that an icon can't be loaded I would assume the following:

The sharing menu shows a list of apps to share the selected content with. This list shows for each app it's app icon plus the app name.

It looks like one of the installed apps, that is shown in the sharing apps list, has a problem loading the app icon. Unfortunately the error log has no indicator which app icon fails to load.

Unless you recently installed a system update the problem is caused by one specific app that has been installed or updated recently recently.

Note: The sharing list is AFAIK automatically generated by the content type to be shared. Each app contains in it's manifest rules and content types it can accept. Upon installation these information is AFAIR copied into a central system-wide XML file (don't remember the exact file name). Hence by modifying this file it would be possible to remove certain apps from the sharing menu, however this XML file is updated/modified if you install or update an app. Hence the manual changes may be overwritten frequently (I never tried this therefore I don't have any experience how long a modification can last in this XML file).